# Valid Query in Oracle SQL developer is invalid in SSIS

Tags: oracle, variables, ssis

Here's how my query looks like :

Edit (I have near to none experience with PLSQL, I just read on some post if you're using Begin/End in your script, you no longer can use plain select, you should insert that result into somewhere! ) can this be the reason the query doesn't work in SSIS? )

```
   Variable x1 Number
   Variable x2 Number
   Variable x3 Number




   Variable x20 Number


   Begin  select user_defined_function(parameters) into x1 from dual; 
    select user_defined_function(parameters) into x2 from dual; 
    select user_defined_function(parameters) into x3 from dual; 


    select user_defined_function(parameters) into x20 from dual; 

   End;
    / 

    with Q1 as (....) 
    , Q2 as (....)
    , Q3 as (...)

    Select * from Q1,Q2,Q3 joining together
```

The query works in SQL developer, however I have to use execute script instead of f5. otherwise it will prompt for variable values.

As I suspected, the query in its current format doesn't work in SSIS. I get the error INVALID SQL STATEMENT 900

Comment: Do you intend on providing the variable values at runtime? Often with Oracle I've had to resort to a dynamically generated SQL string.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the variable values are supposed to be retrieved via the select statements user defined functions. I won't enter anything

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid does this mean what I think it means ? 
The lack of support for parameterized queries in the various Oracle connection managers is an unfortunate limitation in SSIS.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes you're going to find this difficult. You could experiment and try and get it working

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid does that mean my query can't have variables to run in SSIS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224384/discussion-between-ariox66-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: Is not the *un-balance* between the four `Begin` and the only one `End` the problem?

Comment: I removed the SQL Developer tag and I added the ssis tag. Obviously you have a question about ssis, and how it works with Oracle - not about SQL Developer.

Comment: @mathguy I think the way I defined the variables and works only with execute script button in SQL developer has something to do with the fact that the query doesn't work in ODBC connection of SSIS

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thanks for picking that up, I fixed it here. my actual script didn't have this issue

Comment: Please, scale down your example to **only one variable**, clarify what do you mean with the `parameters` as the *argument* of the function, show a simple query that uses the variable. AKA *minimal reproducible example*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use additional CTO for passing the results of the *user_defined_function* into the main query, such as

```
with  
x1 as (
   select user_defined_function(parameters) as x1 from dual), 
x2 as (
   select user_defined_function(parameters) as x2 from dual),  
...
```

In your main query instead of using

```
column1 = x1
```

you would write

```
column1 = (select x1 from x1)
```

This approach eliminates the need of *variables* and PL/SQL *blocks*, and use a pure `SQL`

Comment: Yeah, apparently you can't have PLSQL blocks with plain select in ODBC connections of SSIS

Comment: Actually you are using the SQL*Plus  syntax of [`VARIABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) which would not work quite sure. You may try with [`DECLARE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-568AC23F-1BC3-444E-855E-BF2EC4EEB14B) to define variable which would be PL/SQL